# Remainder of the polynomial

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

A polynomial function $f(x)$  with real coefficients leaves the remainder $15$ when divided by $x-3$, and the remainder $2x+1$ when divided by $(x-1)^2$. Then the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $(x-3)(x-1)^2$ is?
*What I have thought-*
The remainder must be of the form $ax^2+bx+c$. Now applying the remainder theorem, I am able to find $2$ equations in $a,b,c$ . eg
Let $f(x)$=$(x-3)$$h(x)$+$15$             ...................................(1)
Also let $f(x)=(x-3)(x-1)^2g(x)+ax^2+bx+c$...........................(2)
Put $x=3$ and using (1) we get $15=9a+3b+c$ 
Similarly I can get another equation using the other information given. But I am only able to get 2 equations in 3 variables. From where do I get the 3rd equation in $a,b,c$ and hence the remainder?

Comment: Calculate derivatives both members

Comment: Sorry to mislead you. I know calculus. I have removed the tag. And I think @medicu comment will help

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ f(x) = 2x\!+\!1+ (x\!-\!1)^2 (c + (x-3)g(x))\,$ and $\,15 = f(3) = 7+4c\ $ so $\ c = \,\ldots$

Comment: I am not able to figure out what you did..

Comment: @Mridul Since $f(x)$ has remainder $2x+1$ when divided by $(x-1)^2$ we can write $f(x) = 2x+1 + (x-1)^2 h(x).\,$ Now write $h(x) = c + (x-3)g(x)$ then evaluate at $\,x=3$ to solve for $c.\ \ $

Comment: okay... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\frac{1}{4}(x-1)^2-\frac{1}{4}(x+1)(x-3)=1.
$$
You can get this by dividing $(x-1)^2$ by $x-3$. So take
$$
f(x)=15\frac{1}{4}(x-1)^2-(2x+1)\frac{1}{4}(x+1)(x-3).
$$
Then the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $x-3$ is 15 and by $(x-1)^2$ is $2x+1$ since $(x+1)(x-3)=[(x-1)+2][(x-1)-2]=(x-1)^2-4$.